# How to bind Ctrl-Super-[?

Tags: key-bindings

I tried `(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-[") 'xxx)` but when I use it I get:

```
<C-s-268632091> is undefined
```

Comment: How have you "tried"?  How do you "use it"?  Please clarify.

Comment: This is a previous bug that was fixed in the master branch a few months ago.  Emacs 26.1; however, does not include the fix.  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-s-[") (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello-world")))` will work on Emacs 27.0.50 built `--with-ns` in the master branch.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks!

Comment: OP: Please state your Emacs version. @lawlist: Consider posting your comment as an answer. Thx.

Comment: You've now clarified "what you have tried", but not the "how do you use it".  Tell us which keys you type (how did you get a "super" key?), under which OS/GUI, with which version of Emacs.

Comment: I solved this with a sequence of expressions like this:

    `(define-key key-translation-map [C-s-268632065] [?\C-\s-a])`
 ...
    `(define-key key-translation-map [C-s-268632091] [?\C-\s-\[])`

When Emacs gets this fixed, these translations will remain harmless.